# How should I ask my boss if I can get off early?

Tags: united-states, leave

I have physical therapy so I just requested seven days to get off early, and my supervisor seemed very annoyed. Now I have an ultrasound coming up, and I really don't want to make my supervisor mad. How should I ask him about getting off early?

Location : United States.

Comment: why can't you do it after hours? Or during a break

Comment: I work until 8 at night, and I don't have breaks (except lunch, but it is only half an hour and is about 20 minutes away from the hospital)

Comment: What country are you in, that might affect the answer.

Comment: @lijat United States

Comment: Why not before hours?

Comment: Have you tried to explain to him that this physical therapy is very essential to your well-being (physical health) ? If you can convince him nicely, then do you think that he would at least be willing to arrange for your to take some time off and still ensure that the work is done properly (i.e, either you can make up some time or some coworker can take over temporarily during those hours) ?

Comment: Can you get a Doctor’s note? That would sort the issue.

Comment: Does leaving early mean that you do not work the hours at all? Can you work an additional day that makes up the hours?

Answer (score 5):

If you finish at 8PM then you should be able to organise these activities for the mornings before work. Which would negate the need to create any drama at work. It's normally a good idea to separate your work from your personal issues whenever possible. This is perhaps why your supervisor is annoyed.

If it can't be arranged which seems unlikely, then just ask and explain why you need time off at night to get an ultrasound done.

If you're doing shift work it's often better for all concerned to exchange shifts rather than try and get someone to cover part of a shift. The downside is it's sometimes easier just to let you go and replace with someone who can work full time reliably.

Answer (score 3):

Learn a bit about negotiation. It'll be useful for the rest of your life. I'd start with something like,

"I'm about to make you really frustrated. You'll think I'm making unreasonable demands, in light of what I've already asked of you.

"I have been granted early leave for seven days. This is already very generous of you. I understand what a tough position I'm putting you in. Unfortunately, I have to ask for even more.

I would like to get off early also on ____."

Then silence. Let them react, or vent, or whatever it is they need to do. Then continue.

"I don't want to put you on the spot. How can I help this go over with your superiors as well as possible?"

There are several components to this:

- You label their response ahead of time to diminish the emotion associated with it,
- You acknowledge their generosity,
- You ask for something surprisingly small given the introduction,
- You use open-ended how questions to engage their problem solving,
- You recognise that they are also under demands from their boss, and you and them are a team that want them to look good in front of their boss.

Of course, tailor this for your boss. Maybe you don't think they're under pressure from their bosses. Then strike the part about superiors and go with a more generic "How can we make this work?"

I recommend reading Never Split the Difference to start out on your journey to become a better negotiator.

---

Of course, I'd also look for a different employer if this one is giving you crap simply because you are a human being with personal needs outside of work.

Comment: I'm not claiming to be a great negotiator, but opening a negotiation with "I'm about to frustrate you with a demand that I know to be unreasonable" seems like a really, really weird way to start. If I were on the other side of that negotiation, I'd be saying no before you even got to asking your question - you'd be putting all the leverage in my hands, which doesn't seem a great tactic. But then, I'm not a great negotiator, so what do I know. (Can't argue with your final paragraph though; I don't see this situation as a negotiation, if someone needs time off for health reasons, they get it).

Comment: Making the other person feel as though they have all the leverage (even when they do not) is deliberate. People in general are more cooperative when they feel in control of the situation. In contrast, cornered people are more likely to be defensive and look for ways to say no, which is a way to regain control. (Another good book on the subject is "Start With No", which is about negotiating by leading people to say no to the things you both would want to avoid. Again, one of the powers of that approach is that both parties feel like they are in charge, resulting in more creative solutions.)

Comment: (How do you know whether someone truly has all the leverage? When they do, they walk away. As long as people talk to you, you have something they want.)

Comment: OK, but I mean, in this situation, the boss DOES have leverage, and CAN "walk away" (say no). Giving them the opportunity, motive, and means to do so, before even making the case why they shouldn't, seems like a terrible and counter-productive strategy. But we're getting off-topic. Suffice to say that I do not find this answer compelling and let's leave it at that.

Comment: Saying no and walking away is not the same thing. Saying no is fine -- that's how we know we need to negotiate in the first place. If everyone just agreed right away there would be no negotiation. A no is a perfectly appropriate way to start a negotiation, often even desirable for the reasons mentioned above. It's all perfectly coherent and aligns well with psychological research on collaboration, security, emotions and all the rest that goes into negotiation. If you (like I once did) find this counterintuitive, I can strongly recommend reading up on it. It's fascinating and helpful!

Comment: Of course, it's possible the boss would actually really walk away in this situation. That sort of total communication breakdown would be devastating for both the worker's and manager's performance, and the effects of it would be obvious soon enough, so only a very incompetent manager would do that. (Further signs to look for employment elsewhere.)

Answer (score 1):

Without background, leaving early for 7 days sounds excessive, but I don't know the situation. Is there any way to cut back on that to make room for the ultrasound, it'd be recommended. You'll have more opportunity to shave off time in a 7-day run than you will in a 1-day event, that may garner flexibility from the boss for the ultrasound.

Making up the time also works quite well, if it makes sense for the type of job that you have. My employees make up time quite often - for example if someone has to get their car worked on, they will be out for 3 hours - they just stay until 8pm instead of leaving at 5, no biggie. But it depends on the job.

Perhaps if you can't make up time for the ultrasound, you could make up time from the other 7 days to garner more flexibility from the boss.

Another idea might be to schedule the physical therepy so that it's more spread out, and is not so compressed. It's much easier to maintain leaving 2 days early for 3 weeks than it is 7 days in a row.

If these are health issues, you just might have to put up with his grumble, as he might just have to put up with your absence. You can only satisfy others so much, to not risk your own health doing it. And if you end up having to works somewhere else, at least you have your health.